# Improve performance of subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

Here is my query which works using two subqueries and temporary tables:

```
select visit.pid, visit.pidvnum, visit.hpv16, visit.qc_hst
FROM visit,
    (select distinct x.pid  from
        (select pid from visit where visit.qc_hst = 1) x,
        (select pid from visit where visit.hpv16 = 1) y
    where x.pid = y.pid) as subtbl
where visit.pid = subtbl.pid
AND (visit.qc_hst = 1 OR visit.hpv16 =1);
```

Is there a way to rewrite this query to eliminate one or both of the subqueries? I've also used an IN clause with the same two subqueries, but that's even worse. I can't index the fields like qc_hst and hpv16 since there are dozens of them, and any of them could potentially be part of the query.

Here is a sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68bd6/6/0

Thanks a lot - I'm really banging my head against the wall on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query appears to be looking for records where a pid has both those conditions being met.  The following is an alternative approach:

```
select v.pid, v.pidvnum, v.hpv16, v.qc_hst
from visit v join
     (select v.pid
      from visit v
      where visit.qc_hst = 1 or visit.hpv16 = 1
      group by pid
      having SUM(v.qc_hst = 1) > 0 and sum(v.hpv16 = 1) > 0
     ) vp
     on v.pid = vp.pid
where visit.qc_hst = 1 or visit.hpv16 = 1
```

An index on `visit(pid)` will probably help any of the queries run faster.

Comment: That's right - both conditions need to be met on a pid (which is the parent key) but not on a pidvnum (which is the primary key). Your solution looks pretty good - the "explain" looks a heck of a lot better! However, it is a bit "wordy", which will make the generic coding of it in Java a bit tricky. I'll let you know how it works tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work quite spunkily, even when joining a couple more downstream tables - which is what was killing me. It works for me!